# sessions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading Agile web Development to learn Rails 3.0. The author is teaching us how to use sessions using this create method in the sessions controller.

```
def create 

if user = User.authenticate(params[:name], params[:password])
session[:user_id] = user.id
redirect_to admin_url
else
redirect_to login_url, :alert => "Invalid user/password combination"
end 

end
```

In the line

session[:user_id] = user.id

does the symbol `:user_id` exist somewhere before he assigns `user.id` to it? or is this symbol :user_id created at the moment that he assigns user.id to it?  Is there a set number of symbols that belong to this 'session' or can you basically just create something with any name and assign anything to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is created dynamically on the fly. You can see what is in the session by using the debugger and typing `p session`. If you are only storing string data, then you can pretty must store whatever you want, though there are size limitations. The default session is stored in a cookie, though you can also set your SessionStore to be on the server-side as well.

I'm not sure if you can change the name using a config file, but the `session` hash is a special variable that Rails uses. So you should stick to doing `session[:my_var] = "whatever'`

Comment: so you could have named it something else (assuming you didn't want to follow the naming conventions) ?